# Issue getting google workspace file (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, frontend, base64, google-workspace

Im calling request from google workspace file with gapi using this code

```js
gapi.client.drive.files.export({
  fileId: fileId,
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
})
```

from that code i get response back of base64 string to convert as a blob but when i open file in google docs or msword file is corrupt and not working but if i change mimeType into `application/pdf` it working

same thing also happen in if i request file with `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

am i doing something wrong here or i there is other way to getting file workspace

md5Checksum is not available

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `from that code i get response back of base64 string to convert as a blob but when i open file in google docs or msword file is corrupt and not working but if i change mimeType into application/pdf it working`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: actually this issue was solved i will post answer for it tonight

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to wait for your answer.

Comment: @Tanaike i already post the answer for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution for this issue according to this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) we have two type we can download from google drive.

here my code how i request for file

```
const res = await drive
            .files
            .export({
                    fileId: fileId,
                     mimeType: yourMimeTarget
                    })
                    .then(res => res)
const blob_file = fetch(`data:${yourMimeTarget};base64,${btoa(res.body)}`)
                 .then(res => res.blob())
```

so after you fetch google workspace file you will get base64 string than you can convert it into blob

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) for `files.get`:

> **Response**

> By default, this responds with a Files resource in the response body. If you provide the URL parameter `alt=media`, then the response includes the file contents in the response body. Downloading content with `alt=media` only works if the file is stored in Drive. **To download Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides use [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) instead**. For further information on downloading files, refer to Download files.

Comment: sorry i wrong copy my code it should export but still same issue occur